# How to specify pylintrc config values, one on each line?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I am using a `.pylintrc` in my project root directory to control the **PyLint** messages I get when I run it on my project.

There are many options in pylintrc that take a comma separated list of values. For example:

```
[MASTER]

disable=relative-import,invalid-name,missing-docstring
```

In my actual pylintrc, this list of values can be quite long. **Is there a way to specify such values, one on each line?**

This did not work:

```
disable=relative-import,\
invalid-name,\
missing-docstring
```

This did not work either:

```
disable=relative-import
disable+=invalid-name
disable+=missing-docstring
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify a `disable` across several lines, use the following:

```
disable=relative-import,
    invalid-name,
    missing-docstring
```

That is:

- no continuation character `\`; and
- indent the subsequent lines.

Comment: This is standard python [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html) format which uses [RFC822 style](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822.html#section-3.1.1) `field: field-body` format

Answer (score -1):

Em, you can add your config line by line, I'm use it in my project.

pylint explain the keyword `disable` as:

```
# Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You
# can either give multiple identifiers separated by comma (,) or put this
# option multiple times (only on the command line, not in the configuration
# file where it should appear only once).You can also use "--disable=all" to
# disable everything first and then reenable specific checks. For example, if
# you want to run only the similarities checker, you can use "--disable=all
# --enable=similarities". If you want to run only the classes checker, but have
# no Warning level messages displayed, use"--disable=all --enable=classes
# --disable=W"
```

if you can disable others, for example, im my project, pylint give me this informations,

```
C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
R1705: Unnecessary "elif" after "return" (no-else-return)
```

but i want ignore three message, so i add them in `disable` tags, like this

```
disable=unnecessary-lambda,
        no-else-return,
        too-many-branches
```

then pylint dont't report hte three message